# Include JS file in Extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

Unable to get the bootstrap datetimepicker.full.js in my extension.
I have tried the below code:

List.html

```
    <head>
        <script src="jhttps://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
        <script src="{f:uri.resource(path:'JS/datetimepicker.full.js')}"></script>
        <script>$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();</script>
    </head>
    <f:section name="content">
        <input type="text" id="datetimepicker"/>            ..
```

setup.ts

```
page.includeJS.HsRoombooking = EXT:hs_roombooking/Resources/Public/JS/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js
```

Could you suggest what is missing?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the wrong script src `jhttps`?

Comment: Hi Peter, I am sorry for the typo. It is     
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

Comment: I think `f:uri.resource` needs a second parameter `extensionName`. Otherwise you need to specify the full path to datetimepicker.full.js. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/Resource.html for details.

Comment: extensionName is not mandatory field hence I did not try it. However, it does not work as well after adding. In setup.ts is there a special place where it should be included? I have included the JS File at the end of the file..is it correct ?

Comment: Hi Perter, I checked it on firefox, it works!! it does not work with safari.Any suggestions what could be done?